# Specify height width of the view to support multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android

I have created the activity with a button. I need to specify the height and width of the button like below.

```
 Button btn=new Button(this);
 btn.setWidth(100); 
 btn.setHeight(100);
```

For multiple screen support is it a right way to specify the size of the view . Guide me to set the height and width to the view.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you want to determine the button size. Basically you have two options

1. Constants like `FILL_PARENT` or `WRAP_CONTENT`
2. A number

If you choose the 2nd way, you must also choose a strategy, eg

- 30% of the screen/parent width (so it shrinks/grows depending on the screen actual size)
- 1 inch on all screens

The former is trivial: just get the width of the target element (either via `DisplayMetrics` if it's the whole display, or with `getWidth()` if it's a `View`) and multiply it by your coefficient.

The latter requires you to know the *density* of the display, ie *how big is a pixel on the device*. For example by doubling the density, the *pixel width* will halve

```
DENSITY   PIXEL SIZE
100 dpi   1/100 in
200 dpi   1/200 in
```

So if you want your button to be 1 inch wide on all possible devices, you can use

```
button.setWidth(1 * (int) metrics.xdpi); //1 inch * DisplayMetrics.xdpi
```

There is a little variant if you know the size in pixels on a MDPI device, ie a device where  one DIP is one pixel on an approximately 160 dpi screen. In this case you can use the following

```
button.setWidth(100 * metrics.density);
```

This is the javadoc for [`DisplayMetrics.density`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density):

> The logical density of the display. This is a scaling factor for the
>   Density Independent Pixel unit, where one DIP is one pixel on an
>   approximately 160 dpi screen (for example a 240x320, 1.5"x2" screen),
>   providing the baseline of the system's display. Thus on a 160dpi
>   screen this density value will be 1; on a 120 dpi screen it would be
>   .75; etc. This value does not exactly follow the real screen size (as
>   given by xdpi and ydpi, but rather is used to scale the size of the
>   overall UI in steps based on gross changes in the display dpi. For
>   example, a 240x320 screen will have a density of 1 even if its width
>   is 1.8", 1.3", etc. However, if the screen resolution is increased to
>   320x480 but the screen size remained 1.5"x2" then the density would be
>   increased (probably to 1.5).

Answer (score 0):

@Karthick If your button is not used in xml of android layout then you can do below thing for set Button width and Height.

Use Below code to get known what is device height and width.

```
   int public static int LDPI_BUTTONSIZE=100;
   int device_height;
   int device_width;
   WindowManager wm=getWindowManager();;
   DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
   wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
   device_width=dm.widthPixels;
   device_height=dm.heightPixels;
```

From Above Code you will decide in which screen of your android device ,for Example you can refer this link of developer [click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). in that  Refer Table No 3.

Now if your device is LDPI then you can set Button value like this.

```
     Button btn=new Button(this);
     btn.setWidth(LDPI_BUTTONSIZE); 
     btn.setHeight(LDPI_BUTTONSIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to convert pixels to dp's. You can do this with `TypedValue`.

Example:

```
int buttonWidthInPixels = 100;
float buttonWIdthInDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                        buttonWidthInPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
button.setWidth((int) buttonWidthInDp);
```

If instead you want to convert to SP (for text), use `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` as the first parameter for `applyDimension()`. See [this page on the Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html).